# Why foreach creating only one value in array?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, module, prestashop

I create a module for PrestaShop 1.6. I have trouble getting the columns created by this module in the table. I have no idea what might be wrong. '$fields' only takes the last column. '$result' is ok. As if PHP did not create an index.

```
public function getNewDescriptionFields()
{
    $db = Db::getInstance();
    if(!$db)
        return false;

    $result = $db->ExecuteS('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '. _DB_PREFIX_ .'product_lang');                 
    if(!$result)
        return false;

    $fields = array();
    foreach($result as $key => $field);
    {
        $fields[] = $field['Field'];
    }

    file_put_contents('/home/www/test4', var_export($fields, true));
    file_put_contents('/home/www/test3', var_export($result, true));
    $fields = preg_grep("/desc([0-9]?[0-9])_(name|text)/", $fields);
    return $fields;
}
```

From test3 (part):

```
  19 => 
  array (
    'Field' => 'desc4_text',
    'Type' => 'text',
    'Null' => 'YES',
    'Key' => '',
    'Default' => NULL,
    'Extra' => '',
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    'Field' => 'desc5_name',
    'Type' => 'varchar(64)',
    'Null' => 'YES',
    'Key' => '',
    'Default' => NULL,
    'Extra' => '',
  ),
  21 => 
  array (
    'Field' => 'desc5_text',
    'Type' => 'text',
    'Null' => 'YES',
    'Key' => '',
    'Default' => NULL,
    'Extra' => '',
  ),
  22 => 
  array (
    'Field' => 'desc6_name',
    'Type' => 'varchar(64)',
    'Null' => 'YES',
    'Key' => '',
    'Default' => NULL,
    'Extra' => '',
  ),
  23 => 
  array (
    'Field' => 'desc6_text',
    'Type' => 'text',
    'Null' => 'YES',
    'Key' => '',
    'Default' => NULL,
    'Extra' => '',
```

From test3:
`array ( 0 => 'desc6_text', )`

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the foreach line, and try again. I'm not sure how $field is even defined after that.

Comment: Apparently $key and $field stay even after the loop is completed. Ignore the second sentence of my comment. Kamran's answer explains the problem with the semi.

Comment: If you aren't going to use `$key` don't declare it in the foreach loop.  Your regex pattern can/should be `/desc\d+_(name|text)

Comment: OMG! I was fighting with this code about 3 hours. Thanks very much for everyone. For real it was only one char wrong. Thanks @mickmackusa for additional solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using ; at the end of foreach loop and loop body ends up at the first ; so please remove it. 
Code should be like this for foreach

```
foreach($result as $key => $field)
{
  $fields[] = $field['Field'];
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f546b24505d8e2868b069085237e6b2cca46e8f)